# Limiting the time that a function processes in an R for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to apply a function ("foo" for this explanation) to tranform a vector of data into another value.  This function takes the data as an input, and needs submit forms to webpages.  Sometimes, this goes quickly, and other times, it can a long time.  I would like to run the for loop (or equivalent apply function) in a way that skips over the items that take too long.  I have tried to limit the time the loop runs before skipping to the next to 5 seconds using the following:

```
pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 1, max = 100, style = 3)
storage <- matrix(nrow = sample.length, ncol = 2)

for(i in 1:100){  
     s <- Sys.time()  
     storage[i,] <- try(foo(data.vec[i]), TRUE)  
     if (Sys.time() - s >5) {next}  
     # update progress bar  
     setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)  
}  
close(pb)
```

I think that I must not be understanding how to apply the 'next' condition in a for loop.  have searched to find a clearer explanation, but not getting any luck here.

Comment: Your foo() does not return to Sys.time before it is finished. I you want to achieve the skipping, you have to add similar code in the foo function; or run foo in a separate thread, but that's not easy.

Comment: The `evalWithTimeout` example is the way to go.  Otherwise: Perhaps the actual function you're using to call web pages (or whatever) has a built-in timeout argument? Worth digging into the documentation if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`withTimeout()` from package `R.utils`, in concert with `tryCatch()`, might provide a cleaner solution.

For example:

```
require(R.utils)

for(i in 1:5) {
    tryCatch(
        expr = {
            withTimeout({Sys.sleep(i); cat(i, "\n")}, 
                         timeout = 3.1)
            }, 
        TimeoutException = function(ex) cat("Timeout. Skipping.\n")
    )
}

# 1 
# 2 
# 3 
# Timeout. Skipping.
# Timeout. Skipping.
```

In the artificial example above:

- The first argument to `withTimeout()` contains the code to be evaluated within each loop.
- The `timeout` argument to `withTimeout()` sets the time limit in seconds.
- The `TimeoutException` argument to `tryCatch()` takes a function that is to be executed when an iteration of the loop is timed out.

Comment: My loop is breaking. How to resume it? ` Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Operation was aborted by an application callback `

Comment: Same issue here. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on getting a loop to work in foreach with %dopar% so running an error message has caused me a headache, since this will break the loop.

I create the skip variable each time, and when timeout occurs, the loop goes to the next iteration. Hopefully avoiding any 'stop' or 'break' when used with partnering functions.

```
    for(i in 1:5) {
     res=NULL
     skip=FALSE
    tryCatch(
      {res= withTimeout({Sys.sleep(i); 
       cat(i, "\n")},  timeout = 3.1, 
       onTimeout='error')
        }, 
     TimeoutException = function(ex){skip <<- 
        TRUE})
    if(skip){next}
}
```