# How do I time out a lapply when a list item fails or takes too long?

Tags: r, multicore, plyr

For several efforts I'm involved in at the moment, I am running large datasets with numerous parameter combinations through a series of functions. The functions have a wrapper (so I can `mclapply`) for ease of operation on a cluster. However, I run into two major challenges.

a) My parameter combinations are large (think 20k to 100k). Sometimes particular combinations **will** fail (e.g. survival is too high and mortality is too low so the model never converges as a hypothetical scenario). It's difficult for me to suss out ahead of time exactly which combinations will fail (life would be easier if I could do that). But for now I have this type of setup:

```
failsafe <- failwith(NULL, my_wrapper_function)
# This is what I run
# Note that input_variables contains a list of variables in each list item
results <-  mclapply(input_variables, failsafe, mc.cores = 72)
# On my local dual core mac, I can't do this so the equivalent would be:
results <-  llply(input_variables, failsafe,  .progress = 'text')
```

The skeleton for my wrapper function looks like this:

```
my_wrapper_function <- function(tlist) {
    run <- tryCatch(my_model(tlist$a, tlist$b, tlist$sA, tlist$Fec, m = NULL) , error=function(e) NULL)
...
return(run)
}
```

Is this the most efficient approach? If for some reason a particular combination of variables crashes the model, I need it to return a `NULL` and carry on with the rest. However, I still have issues that this fails less than gracefully.

b) Sometimes a certain combination of inputs **does not** crash the model but takes too long to converge. I set a limit on the computation time on my cluster (say 6 hours) so I don't waste my resources on something that is stuck. How can I include a timeout such that if a function call takes more than x time on a single list item, it should move on? Calculating the time spent is trivial but a function mid simulation can't be interrupted to check the time, right?

Any ideas, solutions or tricks are appreciated!

Comment: have you looked into setTimeLimit() or http://www.inside-r.org/node/81211? Might be what you need.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may well be able to manage graceful-exits-upon-timout using a combination of `tryCatch()` and `withTimeout()` from the **R.utils** package.
[See also this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652681/limiting-the-time-that-a-function-processes-in-an-r-for-loop/8653049#8653049), which presents similar code *and* unpacks it in a bit more detail.

```r
library(R.utils)
    
myFun <- function(x) {Sys.sleep(x); x^2}

## withTimeout() times out evaluation after 3.1 seconds, and then
## tryCatch() handles the resulting error (of class "TimeoutException")
## with grace and aplomb.
myWrapperFunction <- function(i) {
    tryCatch(expr = withTimeout(myFun(i), timeout = 3.1), 
             TimeoutException = function(ex) "TimedOut")
}
    
sapply(1:5, myWrapperFunction)
# [1] "1"        "4"        "9"        "TimedOut" "TimedOut"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Josh. I'm testing this out on my cluster now (works fine locally but not sure the timeout plays nicely on a cluster).

Comment: Function `evalWithTimeout()` has been defunct in `R.utils` 2.7.0 (2018-08-27) and removed in `R.utils` 2.9.0 (2019-06-13). Use function `withTimeout()` instead. See [here](https://henrikbengtsson.github.io/R.utils/news/index.html#deprecated-and-defunct-2-7-0) and [here](https://henrikbengtsson.github.io/R.utils/news/index.html#deprecated-and-defunct-2-9-0).

Comment: @user343233 Thanks! I've edited the answer to reflect that change.