# run a function for specified time in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a function to run for a specified amount of time, at the moment I'm trying to use the `system.time` function. I can't figure out how to define a new variable that takes on cumulative value the function running, then put it into a while loop.

```
timer<-(system.time(simulated_results<-replicate(n=1,simulation(J,10000,FALSE,0.1),simplify="vector"))[3])

print(timer)

while(cumsum(timer)<15){
    print(cumsum(timer)) 
    simulated_results<-replicate(n=10000,simulation(J,10000,FALSE,0.1),simplify="vector")
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!!!

Comment: You might find `evalWithTimeout()` from the **R.utils** package helpful. [Here is one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952724/how-do-i-time-out-a-lapply-when-a-list-item-fails-or-takes-too-long/10953354#10953354) of how it can be used, in a slightly more complicated situation than you're asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run some code for a specified number of seconds, you can try the following :

```
start <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
duration <- 5
results <- NULL
while(as.numeric(Sys.time())-start < duration) {
  results <- c(results, replicate(...))
}
```

Of course, you have to change the value of `duration` (in seconds), and replace `replicate(...)` with your code.

Comment: I've just tried using the answer suggested by Juba so I've tried: 

    start <- as.numeric(Sys.time())
    duration <- 5

    while(as.numeric(Sys.time())-start < duration) {
         simulated_results<-replicate(n=10000,simulation(J,10000,FALSE,0.1),s   implify="vector")
    }

but the functions not putting its results into the new vector "simulated_results"

Comment: @user1987097 With your code, the `simulated_results` vector is replaced by the `replicate()` result after each iteration, so you have to append your new results to the previous ones each time (see edited answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `tryCatch` approach and the package **R.utils** for this task. For example, consider the following code

```
fun_test = function(test_parameter){
  
  result <- 1+test_parameter #some execution
  return(result)
}
time = 10 #seconds
res <- NULL
tryCatch({
  res <- R.utils::withTimeout({
    check = fun_test(tsp)
  }, timeout = time)
}, TimeoutException = function(ex) {
  message("Timeout. Skipping.")
})
```

This program will run the function `fun_test` for 10 seconds (given by `time`. If the execution is successful in this time, the result is returned as `res`, else program is stopped. For more guidance, you can follow this URL
[Time out an R command via something like try()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891073/time-out-an-r-command-via-something-like-try)