# Stop R estimation after given time

Tags: r

I would like to constrain the time of estimation to be performed in R. For example, I would like to stop running estimation of a GARCH model (by function `ugarchfit` from package `rugarch`) after 10 seconds if it has not finished by that time. This is just one example, and I would be interested in a general way to instruct R to stop whatever function which has been running as long as a chosen time limit. 
Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552128/run-a-function-for-specified-time-in-r might help.  And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952724/how-do-i-time-out-a-lapply-when-a-list-item-fails-or-takes-too-long/10953354#10953354

Comment: Solution under the second link worked well! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [run a function for specified time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552128/run-a-function-for-specified-time-in-r)