# How to limit the execution time but save the output in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, time, limit, xgboost

I'm trying to limit the execution time of an analysis, however I want to keep what the analysis already did. 
In my case I'm running `xgb.cv` (from `xgboost` R package) and I want to keep all iterations until the analysis reach 10 seconds (or "n" seconds/minutes/hours).

I've tried the approach mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952724/how-do-i-time-out-a-lapply-when-a-list-item-fails-or-takes-too-long?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it stops after it reaches 10 secs without keeping the iterations previously done.

Here is my code:

```
require(xgboost)
require(R.utils)

data(iris)
train.model <- model.matrix(Sepal.Length~., iris)

dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data=train.model, label=iris$Sepal.Length)

evalerror <- function(preds, dtrain) {
  labels <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
  err <- sqrt(sum((log(preds) -  log(labels))^2)/length(labels))
  return(list(metric = "error", value = err))}

xgb_grid = list(eta = 0.05, max_depth = 5, subsample = 0.7, gamma = 0.3,
  min_child_weight = 1)

fit_boost <- tryCatch(
            expr = {evalWithTimeout({xgb.cv(data  = dtrain,
                  nrounds     = 10000,
                  objective   = "reg:linear",
                  eval_metric = evalerror, 
                  early_stopping_rounds = 300,
                  print_every_n = 100,
                  params = xgb_grid,
                  colsample_bytree = 0.7, 
                  nfold = 5,
                  prediction = TRUE,
                  maximize = FALSE
                  )}, 
                  timeout = 10)
                  },                                        
            TimeoutException = function(ex) cat("Timeout. Skipping.\n"))
```

and the output is

```
#Error in dim.xgb.DMatrix(x) : reached CPU time limit
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you parallelize your task? If so learn about parallel::parLapply

Comment: @Andre. I'm familiar with parallelization but that's not what I want. Thank you.

Comment: What about using a while-loop in some way, where you record the time with sys.time() after each iteration and stop when the difference reaches 10 seconds?

Comment: @Ken. Thank you for your comment. The problem is that I don't know how to keep the iterations within `xgb.cv` (or `xgb.train`) before it timeouts.

Comment: @patL I updated my answer. Might be a little closer to what you and future readers are trying to do. Cheers!

Comment: @dataprincess Thank you again for take your time. The thing is that I want to get all the iterations performed before it timeouts. ;)

Comment: Of course, of course. Well, one step at a time, eh?

Comment: @dataprincess Sure and thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

### Edit - slightly closer to what you want:

Wrap the whole thing with R's `capture.output()` function. This will store all the evaluation output as an R object. Again, I think you're looking for something more, but this is at least local and malleable. Syntax:

```
fit_boost <- capture.output(tryCatch(expr = {evalWithTimeout({...}) ) )
> fit_boost
 [1] "[1]\ttrain-error:2.033160+0.006109\ttest-error:2.034180+0.017467 "  ...
```

### Original answer:

You could also use a [sink](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/io.html). Simply add this line before you start doing the cross validation:

```
sink("evaluationLog.txt")
fit_boost <- tryCatch(
expr = {evalWithTimeout({xgb.cv(data  = dtrain,
                              nrounds     = 10000,
                              objective   = "reg:linear",
                              eval_metric = evalerror, 
                              early_stopping_rounds = 300,
                              print_every_n = 100,
                              params = xgb_grid,
                              colsample_bytree = 0.7, 
                              nfold = 5,
                              prediction = TRUE,
                              maximize = FALSE
)}, 
timeout = 10)
},                                        
TimeoutException = function(ex) cat("Timeout. Skipping.\n"))
sink()
```

Where the `sink()` at the end would normally return output to the console, but in this case it won't because an error is thrown. But once you run this, you can open up `evaluationLog.txt` and viola:

```
[1] train-error:2.033217+0.003705   test-error:2.032427+0.012808 
Multiple eval metrics are present. Will use test_error for early stopping.
Will train until test_error hasn't improved in 300 rounds.

[101]   train-error:0.045297+0.000396   test-error:0.060047+0.001849 
[201]   train-error:0.042085+0.000852   test-error:0.059798+0.002382 
[301]   train-error:0.041117+0.001032   test-error:0.059733+0.002701 
[401]   train-error:0.040340+0.001170   test-error:0.059481+0.002973 
[501]   train-error:0.039988+0.001145   test-error:0.059469+0.002929 
[601]   train-error:0.039698+0.001028   test-error:0.059416+0.003018
```

This isn't perfect, of course. I imagine you want to perform some operations on these and this isn't exactly the best format. However, it's not a tall order to convert this into something more manageable. I haven't yet found a way to save the actual `xgb.cv$evaluation_log` object before the timeout. That is a very good question.

Comment: thank you so much. This is helpful for what I need, despite I can not keep results "inside" `R` Session. It would be great if I get this `evaluationLog` in R so I could handle it. Voted up.

Comment: No problem. For the record I misspelled it in my original post, there's an underscore. But yeah, it's a very interesting issue and I'll keep looking into it. That would be a very nice thing to be able to have saved in R.